# selectionStart in textarea rendered by kendoeditor

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I have applied kendo editor on a textarea and am trying to find the cursor position using selectionStart property.But the value is always returned as 0.How can i achieve this?
I am trying to achieve the following formatting in kendo editor using tab spaces.

ppp     fgh       fjdhghdfgjf
fkgfgj   kfg       kfdjgkf
gj        dflkkj    kfjgkfgj

such that the words are neatly placed one below the other and i don't have to manually correct it using space-bar

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getSelection()` method of the kendoEditor. Cursor position is in `focusOffset` field in object that method returns.

Code:

```
$("#Comments").kendoEditor({
    select: function(e) {
        console.log(e.sender.getSelection().focusOffset);
    }
});
```

Working jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/KuQvs/182/

Comment: thankyou,but i have explained why i wanted the cursor position in detail.Please guide me as to how to achieve it.